# Dynamic Percentile in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I am not sure this is even possible.  I've been trying to figure it out for a while now.
I have 393 days of data of patients in units and the service of the provider taking care of the patient.  There is a count of '1' for each patient for each day.  On 1/1/18 on the 2A Unit, there were 1 Digestive patient, 1 Emergency Surgery, 4 ENT, etc.
I want to build this into a visual. I want it such that if there is no filter, I calculate the 90th percentile for all days. But I want to filter on the data also.  So I select all the Cardiac services and 5 units where they typically stay.  Then the 90th percentile recalculates based on the filters on the visual.
Is this even possible?
Thanks

Sample Data:
[image: SampleData]

Below is the flow I am hoping to get:
[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/percentile-exc-function-dax

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I have that and it works with the total data set.  I need to make it dynamic so that the 90th percentile is calculated after I have filtered.

Comment: Are you creating a 'measure' and are you creating it on the first table? I believe if it is on the first table, the filter selection will update that measure too and updated values would trickle down.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-measures

Comment: Thank you Shivam.  I did not create a measure on the first table.  The first table is the results of the SQL query tapping into SQL Server.  I was hoping I could just filter by Department on the first table and it would cascade to the second table since it is built from the first.  But it just does not seem to do that.  I think it may be because it is a Many to One relationship.  I am not sure how I could use a Measure for this, but there have been other posts that brought up that point too.  Just don't know how that would be any different than filtering on Department in the first table.